# Gradle version catalogue - include local project

Tags: android, gradle

I do use the gradle version catalogue in my projects and now I want to quickly switch from a online source to a local project - how can I do this?

My catalogue looks like following currently:

```
versionCatalogs {

        // TOML Files
        create("androidx") {
            from(files("gradle/androidx.versions.toml"))
        }
        create("deps") {
            from(files("gradle/dependencies.versions.toml"))
        }

        // Rest
        val kotlin = "1.7.10"
        create("tools") {
            version("kotlin", kotlin)
            version("gradle", "7.2.2")
            version("maven", "2.0")
        }
        create("app") {
            version("compileSdk", "32")
            version("minSdk", "21")
            version("targetSdk", "32")
        }
        create("libs") {
            library("kotlin", "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin")
        }
    }
```

Now I want to remove a dependency and replace it with a local project that I would normally add like following:

```
implementation(project(":MyLibrary:Core"))
implementation(project(":MyLibrary:Animations"))
...
```

**Question:**

How can I define projects inside my version catalogue? Either inside a TOML file (I think that's not possible) or at least manually inside the `versionCatalogue` lambda.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced exactly the same problem when I was migrating my KMM project from the `buildSrc` to the version catalogs.

So, answering your question: You can use `version` to store any kind of string, therefore you can put path to a local module as the version. For example, that's how I did in my project:

```
create("projects") {
   version("common-crypto", ":code:common:crypto")
   version("common-cryptoswift", ":code:common:crypto:swift-crypto")
   version("common-jwt", ":code:common:jwt")
   version("common-model", ":code:common:model")
   version("common-utils", ":code:common:utils")
   version("common-test-utils", ":code:common:test-utils")
   version("common-validator", ":code:common:validator")
}
```

And that's how I'm using it to reference the local modules:

```kotlin
val commonTest by getting {
   dependencies {
      ...
      implementation(project(projects.versions.common.test.utils.get()))
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: But what if I want to bundle them? In your example, I still need to write `implementation(...)` several times, but I want to have one - by using bundle

Comment: In my example each project is actually a "version", so I guess the way I listed it is not compatible with "bundling".

If you found out how we can bundle projects as we're able for libraries - I'll be happy to hear it and implement in my project as well :)